# Raspberry PI 4b HDMI no signal

Tags: pi-4, hdmi

I have a problem with my new Raspberry PI 4B and an old Panasonic TV (TX-P46G10E).
It seems there is no signal through my HMDI. But if I test it with a computer display (4K) it works correctly.
Before I tested the same Panasonic TV with a Raspberry PI 3b+, and with this it is working correctly.

I tried all parameters in config.txt ... with any result.
I tried 3 different micro HDMI to HDMI cables and also 2 adapters ... same issue.

So it seems there is no HDMI signal, but if I switch off the Raspberry remotly ... the TV switched off too!
So it seems that CEC is working!

This is my environment:

```
RASP4B:~ # tvservice -s
state 0xa [HDMI CUSTOM RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive

RASP4B:~ # tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 16 modes:
           mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 5: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
           mode 6: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 7: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
  (native) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
           mode 17: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 18: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 19: 1280x720 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 20: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
           mode 21: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 22: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
  (prefer) mode 31: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
           mode 32: 1920x1080 @ 24Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive

RASP4B:~ # tvservice -a
     PCM supported: Max channels: 2, Max samplerate:  48kHz, Max samplesize 16 bits.

RASP4B:~ # tvservice -n
device_name=MEI-Panasonic-TV

RASP4B:~ # tvservice -l
1 attached device(s), display ID's are :
Display Number 2, type HDMI 0
```

The only difference with same command and the 3b+ model is this:

`RASP3BPLUS:~ # tvservice -s
state 0xa [HDMI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive`

*HDMI CEA (16)* instead of *HDMI CUSTOM*.

Do you have some suggestions?
Thanks, bye.
Morgan

Comment: Are you using the connector closest to the USB-C port?  If not try that with a reboot.